# mySQL Operand should contain 1 column error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1241

I am trying to run the query shown below to include the results in a report and am getting an `Operand should contain 1 column` error #1241. I have not been able to figure out the cause of this. If I run this part by itself I do not get any errors: `(pct_return_1 * .25) + (pct_return_2 * .25) + (pct_return_3 * .15) + (pct_return_4 * .15) + (pct_return_5 * .2)`

Here is the code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_5;
CREATE TABLE temp_5 (
    date_value date default NULL,
    pct_return_portfolio double default NULL,
    pct_return_benchmark double default NULL);

INSERT INTO temp_5 (date_value, pct_return_portfolio, pct_return_benchmark)
SELECT
 (date_value,
  (pct_return_1 * .25) +
  (pct_return_2 * .25) +
  (pct_return_3 * .15) +
  (pct_return_4 * .15) +
  (pct_return_5 * .2)
  FROM Temp_4),
pct_return_6)
FROM temp_4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the first occurrence of `FROM Temp_4` (the one just after the second value in the subquery).

Edit: Also double check parenthesis groupings, as in this example:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (field1, field2, field3, field4) (SELECT 'value1 from user input', field1, field2, field3 from table1)
```

Which is given on this page regarding insert subqueries: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html

Comment: I tried your suggestion and below is my actual query. The query did not run successfully. I received the same error message. 
INSERT INTO temp_5 (date_value, pct_return_portfolio, pct_return_benchmark)
  SELECT
   (date_value,
  (
    (pct_return_1 * .25) +
    (pct_return_2 * .25) +
    (pct_return_3 * .15) +
    (pct_return_4 * .15) +
    (pct_return_5 * .2)
  ),
 pct_return_6)
  FROM temp_4;

Comment: In the example I found, the select statement or subquery is completely enclosed in parenthesis. So on your statement, place an open parenthesis before "SELECT" and another after "FROM temp_4" hopefully that works for you. Subqueries are picky!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO temp_5 
  (date_value, pct_return_portfolio, pct_return_benchmark)
SELECT date_value,
       pct_return_1 * .25 + pct_return_2 * .25 + pct_return_3 * .15 + pct_return_4 * .15 + pct_return_5 * .2,
       pct_return_6
  FROM temp_4;
```

Mathematical order of operations ensures that brackets/parenthesis are not necessary.